# how can I find my node.js files in linux, /usr/bin/node is not working

Tags: node.js

I want to find where is my node.js in ubuntu linux system, 
the command:  *which node* gives me the path of  */usr/bin/node*, but when I go to that folder, there is no node folder and files.

can somebody help me?

I installed the node.js by this:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties python g++ make
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Comment: /usr/bin/node is not a folder. It is a binary file.

Comment: I see, but still I don't find it in /usr/bin

Answer (score 23, accepted):

running `dpkg-query -L nodejs` will list the full path to every file belonging to the `nodejs` package. If `/usr/bin/node` is not there (it should be a symlink to `/usr/bin/nodejs`), then something went wrong with the `apt-get install`.

Comment: which node helped me, dpkg-query command not found , need to install it first.

Comment: The question is asking about the Ubuntu linux distribution specifically. `dpkg-query` should be in the base package set and always installed, I believe. If you don't have it at `/usr/bin/dpkg-query` you are probably not on a debian/ubuntu based distribution.

Answer (score 69):

In order to find the installation path, write the below command in the terminal:

```
which node
```

If it doesn't succeed, try this one:

```
which nodejs
```

Same thing for finding npm installation path:

```
which npm
```

If you are on **Windows**, write `where` instead of `which`

Hope, it helps :)

Comment: It did help! Really nice and clear! :)

Answer (score 17):

don't worry `sudo apt-get install nodejs` installs a version of nodejs which is normally outdated. `/usr/bin/nodejs` is therefore fine.

Do some additional work to use only `node` for the command line:

1. install package manager npm: `sudo apt-get install npm`
2. then upgrade npm: `sudo npm cache clear --force && sudo npm install -g npm`
3. next install n: `sudo npm install -g n`
   which is a version manager for node.
4. after this upgrade your node installation: `sudo n stable` this will create a `/usr/bin/node` script which fixes your described issue so you can use `node app.js` to execute your app instead of `nodejs app.js`.

You can downgrade node to a desired version, e.g: `sudo n 0.12.4`

check your version to verify: `node --version`

Comment: Brilliant! My new distro was yet to be recognized apparently. So It's better to install it this way

Comment: `sudo npm cache clear --force` worked in centos 8 stream

Answer (score 2):

If you have both **[Nodejs](https://nodejs.org/)** and **[npm](https://www.npmjs.com/)** installed correctly, just open your terminal:

Run: `npm config ls -l` to see a set of configuration parameters that are internal to npm.

npm is configured from the following sources, sorted by priority:

- **[Command Line Flags](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#command-line-flags)**: `--save-dev, --prefix, --global`
- **[Environment Variables](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#environment-variables)**: `npm_config_foo=bar` or `NPM_CONFIG_FOO=bar`

  - Both are correct values but just know that inside [npm-scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) npm will set its own environment variables and Node will prefer those lowercase versions over any uppercase ones you set.
  - Also you need to use underscores instead of dashes, so `--allow-same-version` would be `npm_config_allow_same_version=true`
- **[npmrc Files](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#npmrc-files)**: There are *four* relevant files:

  1. **per-project**: `/path/to/my/project/.npmrc`
  2. **per-user** defaults to:( `$HOME/.npmrc` ; also configurable via CLI option `--userconfig` or environment variable `$NPM_CONFIG_USERCONFIG` )
  3. **global** defaults to:( `$PREFIX/etc/npmrc` ; also configurable via CLI option `--globalconfig` or environment variable `$NPM_CONFIG_GLOBALCONFIG` )
  4. **npm built-in** configuration file: ( `/path/to/npm/npmrc` )

For those who may be unfamiliar or new to [Nodejs](https://nodejs.org/), [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) and [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#deeper-shell-integration) the user needs to be aware that it's possible to have more then one version of Node on your system.

It's also possible to have Node stored both locally and globally.

With multiple versions and different locations it's possible that `$ which node` may not give you the right location and if you run `$ locate node` your gonna end up with too many locations to sort through.

Using the built-in Node/npm tools to locate Node seems to make the most sense.