# node in ubuntu: can't run without full path despite $PATH setting

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-14.04

A seemingly contradictory set of outcomes:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/node --version
v5.2.0

$ node
The program 'nodejs' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install nodejs

$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

I would appreciate if someone could point out what could possibly be wrong with the configuration of the `$PATH`.

For installing node, I've followed these [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20031849/how-can-i-find-my-node-js-files-in-linux-usr-bin-node-is-not-working/32740546#32740546).

Thanks.

Comment: What is the output of `which node` ?

Comment: You may have forgotten to `export PATH`.

Comment: @Paulpro : `which node` results in `/usr/local/bin/node`

Comment: @alvits `PATH` is exported from .bashrc

Comment: Never mind my previous comment. The real issue is `nodejs` is not found in any directories n the `PATH`. If you know where `nodejs` is located, add its path to `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Despite `source ~/.bashrc` the PATH was not being updated. Yet, upon creating a new terminal with a new bash prompt, then it did: `which node` showed the correct path, and `node` resulted in a prompt. Puzzling. But resolved.

Comment: Wrong. `node` was found, but `nodejs` was nowhere to be found. Nonetheless, I'm glad you fixed your issue :) Cheers!